# PHP error handling and load alternate

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm using geoplugin API for my website that built using Codeigniter. Sometimes if API requests exceed then it gives me an error for one hour like:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: unserialize():
>   Error at offset 0 of 162 bytes

I'm loading that API results in view like this:

```
<?php $this->load->view('options/_country_list.php'); ?>
```

What solution I looking for is, if any PHP error happens in _country_list.php then I want to load another PHP file using if else or any other best way. I'm not sure is it possible or not! If it's possible then how can I do this?

Comment: I dont know what are you doing in your controller before passing it to render.
Share some more code so that can have a look.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I'm directly loading this. There is no relation with the controller. Normally It's run ok until exceeding API calls._country_list.php is similar to this http://www.geoplugin.com/_media/webservices/geoplugin.class.phps

Comment: The final code:  <?php $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
echo "{$geoplugin->countryName}\n"; 
?>